# How to assign dynamic data source to GridView using Entity Framework?

Tags: asp.net, .net, frameworks, entity, procedure

I have an Stored Procedure which may return some unpredictable rows and columns, based on some business logic written in my SP. That is for sure that it will return only one set of Result Set data from this SP.

Whatever the result my SP returns, it should be reflected into my GridView. Due to some framework restrictions, I can not use ADO.Net DataSets/DataTables.

I am using Entity Framework 4.0 for my project and I want some solution to bind my GridView with dynamic nature of DataSource returned by my Stored procedure.

I think, this is very common problem which many developer has encountered in such type of situation. 
Is there anyone who have found some work around to achieve the goal within the boundary line of Entity Framework?

Note: Keep in mind that, I don't want to use ADO.net DataSet or DataTable.

Comment: Are you keeping SP returned data in <List>.Please let me know.

Comment: @Neeraj- I have no idea how can I proceed. Could you please share some code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are fetching data from proc and stored in List like that.

```
List<HRDocumentCheckList> searchJoiningDoc =     GetJoiningDocumentForEdit(ddlCategory.SelectedValue.ToInt32(), false).ToList();

        gvJoiningDocumentTemplate.DataSource = searchJoiningDoc;
        gvJoiningDocumentTemplate.DataBind();
```

Just bind the gridview and set the autogenrated column is false

Hope it will helps you

Comment: I think autogenerated property should be true. But my problem is that I don't know the structure of the resultset. in your sample, you are expecting the ouput from your SP as HRDocumentCheckList type.

Comment: Are you stored fetched data in list .Can you elaborate your process how to fetch data and try to shown on UI